# HOOK-ERROR in after_step: TimeoutException: Message: timeout

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, bdd, python-behave

Sometimes, when my script is run by jenkins i get an error:

```
HOOK-ERROR in after_step: TimeoutException: Message: timeout
(Session info: chrome=69.0.3497.92)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.35.528139 
(47ead77cb35ad2a9a83248b292151462a66cd881),platform=Linux 4.4.0-128-generic x86_64)
```

i cannot reproduce this situation on my local machine. Do you have any idea how can i check and fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
HOOK-ERROR in after_step: TimeoutException: Message: timeout
(Session info: chrome=69.0.3497.92)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.35.528139
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **WebBrowser** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=2.35*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.35*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.35/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v62-64**

- You are using *chrome=69.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v2.43*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.43/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v69-71**

So there is a clear mismatch between the *ChromeDriver v2.35* and the *Chrome Browser v69.0*

---

### Solution

- Upgrade *JDK* to  recent levels [**JDK 8u191**](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [**Version 3.14.0**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  current [**ChromeDriver v2.42**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version between ***Chrome v69-71*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.43 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.43/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Execute your `@Test`.